# Get the total time (hours and minutes) from sum of time difference in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have this kind of .csv (trip, distance and time):

[image]

I would like to calculate the duration of each trip in R.

P.S.: The main problem could be the format of the time.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Provide a reproducible example so it is easier to help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Input data:
Trip Distance Time
34    1.8           17:30
34    1.5           18:00
34    3.0           18:30
34    5.1           19:00
35    3.2           15:32
35    1.1           18:43
36    2.3           16:20
36    3.3           16:25
36    4.0           20:30

Output data:
Trip  Time
34    1:30
35    3:11
36    4:10

Comment: Albin pointed you to the suggestions about providing reproducible examples. Did you read it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. For each trip you have duration:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- tibble(Trip= c(34,34,34,35,35,36, 36, 36, 36),
             Distance = seq(1,9),
             Time= c("17:30", "18:00", "18:30", "17:30","18:00", "17:30", "18:30","19:00", "19:30"))

df %>% mutate(Time = hm(Time)) %>% 
  group_by(Trip) %>% 
  mutate(Trip_time = duration(as.double(tail(Time, n=1)-head(Time, n=1))))
```

PS: your question is poorly written.